# Encoding of PHP error message

Tags: php

I have WebServer on Windows.

In .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding utf-8
php_value default_charset utf-8
```

In script:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
ftp_connect("1");
```

In browser in UTF-8:

```
Warning: ftp_connect() [function.ftp-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������. (
```

Question - Why error message is not in UTF-8?

Comment: Just guessing: php simply prints the error message it got from the OS, in this case it's windows, and AFAIR the encoding of that is windows-1252.

Comment: @Maerlyn Nope, that error message is not cp-1252 (which is ASCII-compatible), but UTF-16. But yes, the problem is that the OS charset doesn't match php's, and php does not translate.

Comment: maybe... thanks, Maerlyn

Answer (score 0):

It seems like PHP got nothing to do with error message right from "getaddrinfo failed:". Misrepresented characters are originating from different source - here from ftp server application. You've checked both web server and PHP side, but not configuration of ftp server.

My best bet would be with checking ftp server.

You could check another error message below your code

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
ftp_connect("1");
//generate some mess resulting in error info
file_get_contents('forsurenonexistingfile');
```

if your error info come in right character representation, mystery is gone.